# CSV reader and parser

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I have implemented a CSV reader. I think I did pretty well. Since CSV is a loosely defined format to begin with I decided to allow some malformations, like anything but a delimiter after an enclosed value.

Maybe someone could point out improvements to this class, I would be happy to know them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication49
{

    public class CsvReader
    {
        private const char Sym_Escape = '"';

        private static int StandardInitialRowSize = 16;

        private StreamReader reader;
        private char delimiter;
        private char[] buffer;
        private int bufferSize;
        private int bufferBound;
        private int bufferPos;
        private bool endReached;
        private bool boundReached;
        private bool returnImplicitRow;
        private int initialRowSize;
        private int valuePos;
        private StringBuilder valueBuilder;

        public CsvReader(Stream stream, char delimiter = ',', int bufferSize = 4096)
        {
            #region check
            if (stream == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
            }

            if (delimiter == Sym_Escape || delimiter == '\r')
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid delimiter", "delimiter");
            }

            if (bufferSize < 128)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid buffer size", "bufferSize");
            }
            #endregion

            this.reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize);
            this.delimiter = delimiter;
            this.buffer = new char[bufferSize];
            this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
            this.initialRowSize = StandardInitialRowSize;
            this.valueBuilder = new StringBuilder(128);

            if (reader.BaseStream.Length == 0)
            {
                returnImplicitRow = true;
            }
        }

        public bool Read(out string[] outRow)
        {
            Assert();

            if (endReached)
            {
                if (returnImplicitRow)
                {
                    returnImplicitRow = false;
                    outRow = new string[1];

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    outRow = null;

                    return false;
                }
            }

            string[] row = new string[initialRowSize];
            int rowSize = initialRowSize;
            int rowPos = 0;

            bool newlineReached = false;

            do
            {
                Assert();

                if (endReached)
                {
                    goto SetValue;
                }

                char chr = buffer[bufferPos++];

                if (chr == Sym_Escape)
                {
                    Assert();

                    if (endReached)
                    {
                        goto SetValue;
                    }

                    valuePos = bufferPos;
                    chr = buffer[bufferPos++];

                    while (true)
                    {
                        #region Regular assertion
                        if (bufferPos == bufferBound)
                        {
                            valueBuilder.Append(buffer, valuePos, (bufferPos - valuePos) - 1);

                            if (reader.EndOfStream)
                            {
                                endReached = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bufferBound = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                bufferPos = 0;
                                valuePos = 0;
                            }

                            boundReached = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            boundReached = false;
                        }
                        #endregion

                        if (chr == Sym_Escape)
                        {
                            if (endReached)
                            {
                                goto SetValue;
                            }

                            chr = buffer[bufferPos];

                            if (chr == Sym_Escape)
                            {
                                if (boundReached)
                                {
                                    valueBuilder.Append(Sym_Escape);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    valueBuilder.Append(buffer, valuePos, bufferPos - valuePos);
                                }

                                bufferPos++;
                                valuePos = bufferPos;

                                Assert();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (!boundReached)
                                {
                                    valueBuilder.Append(buffer, valuePos, (bufferPos - valuePos) - 1);
                                    valuePos = bufferPos;
                                }

                                bufferPos++;

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (boundReached)
                        {
                            valueBuilder.Append(chr);
                        }

                        if (endReached)
                        {
                            goto SetValue;
                        }

                        chr = buffer[bufferPos++];
                    }
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    #region Regular assertion
                    if (bufferPos == bufferBound)
                    {
                        valueBuilder.Append(buffer, valuePos, (bufferPos - valuePos) - 1);

                        if (reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            endReached = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bufferBound = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bufferPos = 0;
                            valuePos = 0;
                        }

                        boundReached = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        boundReached = false;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    if (chr == delimiter)
                    {
                        if (!boundReached)
                        {
                            valueBuilder.Append(buffer, valuePos, (bufferPos - valuePos) - 1);
                            valuePos = bufferPos;
                        }

                        endReached = false;

                        break;
                    }
                    else if (chr == '\r' && !endReached && buffer[bufferPos] == '\n')
                    {
                        if (!boundReached)
                        {
                            valueBuilder.Append(buffer, valuePos, (bufferPos - valuePos) - 1);
                        }

                        bufferPos++;
                        valuePos = bufferPos;

                        Assert();

                        if (endReached)
                        {
                            returnImplicitRow = true;
                        }

                        newlineReached = true;

                        break;
                    }
                    else if (boundReached)
                    {
                        valueBuilder.Append(chr);
                    }

                    if (endReached)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    chr = buffer[bufferPos++];
                }

            SetValue:
                if (rowPos == rowSize)
                {
                    rowSize *= 2;
                    Array.Resize(ref row, rowSize);
                }

                row[rowPos++] = valueBuilder.ToString();
                valueBuilder.Length = 0;
            }
            while (!endReached && !newlineReached);

            if (rowPos < rowSize)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref row, rowPos);
            }

            outRow = row;

            initialRowSize = rowPos;

            return true;
        }

        private void Assert()
        {
            if (bufferPos == bufferBound)
            {
                if (reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    endReached = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bufferBound = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bufferPos = 0;
                    valuePos = 0;
                }

                boundReached = true;
            }
            else
            {
                boundReached = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is some code to do testing

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(OpenFile(@"D:\Users\Administrator\desktop\test.csv"));
            string[] row;

            while (csvReader.Read(out row))
            {
                int len = row.Length - 1;

                for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(Filter(row[i], Char.IsControl));

                    if (i < len)
                    {
                        Console.Write('|');
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string Filter(string str, Func<char, bool> invalidator)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if (!invalidator.Invoke(c))
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static FileStream OpenFile(string filePath)
        {
            return OpenFile(filePath, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }

        public static FileStream OpenFile(string filePath, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare)
        {
            FileStream fs = null;

            try
            {
                fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, fileAccess, fileShare);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            return fs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you didn't just import microsoft.visualbasic.fileio and use the native textfieldparser class?

Comment: @JohnP I would rather not rely on utilities hiding in a language namespace. But eitherway it doesn't sound like an interesting approach.

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger - Fair enough. I've been using it for some widely varied (tab delimited, bar, etc) and it hasn't hiccuped yet. To each his own :)

Comment: In your example `CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(OpenFile(@"D:\Users\Administrator\desktop\test.csv"));`, you're "leaking" an `IDisposable` resource. You should have it as its own variable beforehand within a `using` statement.

Comment: For that matter, `this.reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize);` doesn't get disposed deterministically. Your class should then implement `IDisposable` as well and follow the Disposable Pattern.

Comment: @Jesse the CSV reader is optimized to use an internal buffer, a performance issue would occur if the buffer of any given StreamReader is not the same. Therefore the reader creates its own StreamReader.

Comment: People have already made sure to critique the hundreds of lines method that includes a `goto`, and the fact that you havent disposed your stream. But they seem to have not noticed yet that you also have `catch(Exception) { }`, which is arguably worse. Let's catch and continue when we get an `OutOfMemoryException`! Those aren't important! Yeah, nice plan!

Comment: @Magus I appreciate you bashing my helper method but you could also give the reader a try if it isn't too much to ask.

Comment: `outRow = new string[1]` should be `outRow = new string[0]`.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger My comments still stand, internal buffer or no.

Comment: Leopold - This question is designed to be controversial. Your opening paragraph makes broad, opinionated statements that have no facts to back them (yet). Your opinions about `goto` are also controversial. This question feels like it is trolling. Please remove the hyperbole, or give examples of where your code is more complete than other libraries, more performant, etc. I will be happy to go though and edit this myself in an hour or so.

Comment: @rolfl My claim that CSV is ugly is easily justified by the fact that there are no solid standards explaining the format, clearly CSV does not qualify. IETF made a subtle attempt though. CSV as understood by most has one major flaw, it uses quotes to escape a value, this will replace one problem with another, because now we must use two quotes to escape the quote character. It would have been much better if CSV was introduced with a backslash to escape values, but there doesn't seem a way back without creating confusion and lack of support.

Comment: Was it really necessary to rename this thread to "CSV reader and parser"? Because a reader is a parser using a stream.

Comment: Please do not edit the code in your questions. Please see this meta post. [Is it ok to edit my question for an iterative review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c).

Comment: You can change `OpenFile` to have only one overload with optional arguments.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger - You're making my case for me. Both the generic parser project available on code project and the VB library handle quotes just fine.

Answer (score 14):

Including the signature, scope opening and closing braces, and all the superfluous vertical whitespace you've got here, the `Read` method has 223 lines of code, checks if the end was reached in 7 places and includes 4 `goto` instructions.

Other answers already stated it, but I don't think it can ever be stressed enough: `goto` is a synonym for **bad control flow**; the 220-some lines of code in the method reinforce that: `Read` is, in reality, doing much more than just *reading*, and your code could really benefit from being broken down into several smaller, private methods.

But let's start with the class itself, and its members:

> ```
> private const char Sym_Escape = '"';
> ```

I don't like the name of that constant. Even if it were `SymbolToEscape` I still wouldn't like it. It's a *constant*, it's never going to need to change. People know what to expect of a constant that's called `FourtyTwo`, *it's never going to change.* A double quote can reasonably be expected to remain represented by a `"` - I'd call it `DoubleQuote`, and a line like this would be much easier to understand:

> ```
> valueBuilder.Append(Sym_Escape);
> ```

Versus:

```
valueBuilder.Append(DoubleQuote);
```

The `StandardInitialRowSize` looks like it could be any arbitrary value. Where's the `16` coming from? Why isn't it `0` or `32`? Why is it `static`? Why isn't it `readonly`?

> ```
> private static int StandardInitialRowSize = 16;
> ...
> private int initialRowSize;
> ...
> this.initialRowSize = StandardInitialRowSize;
> ```

Not making this value a constant is probably a good design decision. However one shouldn't reasonably expect the *standard initial row size* to change at any point during the lifetime of an instance of that class, so making it `readonly` would clarify the intent:

```
private static readonly int StandardInitialRowSize = 16;
```

> ```
> this.reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize);
> ```

---

Looking at how the reader is used:

> ```
> CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(OpenFile(@"D:\Users\Administrator\desktop\test.csv"));
> ```

I think it's nice that you provide a constructor that takes a `Stream` parameter, but as a consumer of that class I would also expect to be able to instantiate it like this:

```
var reader = new CsvReader(@"D:\Users\Administrator\desktop\test.csv");
```

...which would require *chained constructors*, one of which taking in a `string path` parameter:

```
public CsvReader(string path, char delimiter = ',', int bufferSize = 4096)
    : this(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
{ }
```

And let the client deal with any exceptions that stem from an invalid file name, or any other exceptions that might be thrown. Your code currently **swallows all of these exceptions** and potentially sends the constructor a `null` reference, which you're guarding against by throwing an `ArgumentNullException` - that's nice and it keeps your class in a consistent/workable state, but it doesn't hold any trace of *why* this situation is happening in the first place - is the file inexistent? is the file locked for editing by another process? by another thread in the same process? by another instance of your reader? does the user have permissions to access that file? By *swallowing* the exception that held that information, you failed to **fail fast** and lost very valuable information, and that makes debugging much harder than it needs to be.

The object is a **reader**. Does the file really need to be opened with `ReadWrite` access? It seems pretty awkward to have a *reader* lock a file for writing when you know from the start that you're not going to write anything.

---

> ```
> if (delimiter == Sym_Escape || delimiter == '\r')
> {
>     throw new ArgumentException("Invalid delimiter", "delimiter");
> }
> ```

I always chuckle when I see *Comma-Separated-Values* data with a delimiter other than a *comma*. But you're being flexible here, and that's good. However this guard clause is likely to evolve into a bunch of `... || ... || ...`, a more maintainable approach would be to use an inline array:

```
if (new[] { Sym_Escape, '\r' }.Contains(delimiter))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid delimiter", "delimiter");
}
```

Now if you want to consider `\n` an invalid delimiter, you can just add it to the array and be done with it.

I don't like the `#region` around the guard clauses, but that's my own personal opinion. I have a strong bias against `#region`, because I found that whenever I thought I needed a `#region` in a *method*, it turned out it was because the *method* was doing too many things and, after refactoring into smaller methods, regions weren't needed anymore; when I thought I needed a `#region` in a *class*, it turned out it was because the *class* was doing too many things and, after refactoring into smaller classes, regions weren't needed anymore.

I don't like labels (what `goto` points to) either, pretty much for the same reason: whenever I *thought* I needed to use a `goto` and jump to a label, it turned out after refactoring and extracting the methods and DRYing up my code, the execution flow untangled before my eyes, and `goto` wasn't needed anymore; without a `goto` to jump to it, a label is pretty much useless, so I stopped using those too.

Yes, `goto` can make your code work. But unless proven otherwise `goto` is **always** a missed refactoring opportunity.

---

On this line:

> ```
> this.reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize);
> ```

You are creating a `StreamReader` instance. The "typical" usage is normally as follows:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, bufferSize))
{
    int c;
    while ((c = reader.Read()) != -1)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `using` block ensures proper disposal of the `StreamReader`. **It's important to dispose of streams** and usually, a `using` block does that automagically.

The only alternative is to call the `Dispose` method manually. And this is what your code is *not* doing. Please see [Using an object that implements IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources. The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a managed object when that object is no longer used. However, it is not possible to predict when garbage collection will occur. **Furthermore, the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged resources such as window handles, or *open files and streams***.
>
> Use the Dispose method of this interface to explicitly release unmanaged resources in
>   conjunction with the garbage collector. The consumer of an object can call this method when the object is no longer needed.
>
> <sub>(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx))</sub>

An easy rule to follow, is that *the object that creates the disposable, is also responsible for disposing the disposable*.

In this case the `CsvReader` class is responsible for creating the reader, using the stream that was passed through the constructor. The reader gets "pinned" into a private field, at *instance* level - and the reason you need to do this is to enable that `while (reader.Read())` client loop. That's a pretty good reason.

You can't call `Dispose` in the constructor, `Read` would throw an `ObjectDisposedException` the minute you try to access the encapsulated reader. You're encapsulating an object that implements `IDisposable` - the only reasonable thing to do is to implement `IDisposable` too, and call the `Dispose` method of the reader instance there.

Then you also enable the `using` block the client code would rightfully be expecting to be able to use.

---

You're using a `StringBuilder`, that's awesome:

> ```
> this.valueBuilder = new StringBuilder(128);
> ```

Where's the `128` coming from? It's probably best to promote that magic number to a `private static readonly` field.

---

I've only scratched the surface, and this answer is getting pretty long already. You have a nice little spaghetti plate there. Refactor, my friend. Refactor. Extract smaller methods: if you can look at a block of code and put a comment above it that says *what* it does (don't do that, it's a bad commenting habit to have), you'd find that everytime you have such a block of code, it can be extracted into its own method pretty neatly.

I have to say something about your `Assert` method though:

1. Bad, bad, bad, bad name.
2. Bad. Name.
3. Bad name.
4. `Assert` says nothing about what that method is doing, and without a parameter and without a return type, only reading the code will tell.

Comment: Impressive work :)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough review.
1. Then why not name Pi to ThreePointOneFourX instead? I think this is silly.
2. StandardInitialRowSize is 16 (2^4) because I assume that most CSV files won't exceed that number of values per row. If my assumption is well-placed then increasing the number would cause overhead. The number is a power of 2 in favor of the computer.
3. Initializing an array for the sole purpose of comparing a character is massive overhead. Two `or` operators are perfectly readable.
4. You (and those before you) were right concerning the dispose pattern as a good practice.

Comment: 5. Those regions called "regular assertion" represent "inlined" code. I've hidden them with regions because they're quite big.
6. I used the method name `Assert` because it assures that the most common pattern in the code (reading the buffer) can persist without error. So it does exactly what it says it does.

Comment: 7. I use an internal buffer instead of `StreamReader.Read` to increase performance by 100 percent. [Here](http://pastebin.com/jJxQDzpT) is another CsvReader that uses the `Read` method. It is incredibly slow. It will work perfectly for small CSV files, but it will fall short for huge CSV files, like those containing alot of scientific records.

Comment: `Assert` clashes with `Debug.Assert`, takes no parameters and returns nothing. This is Code Review; you're asking for other programmers' point of view. If I read your code and say "WTF" you can explain all you want, I still WTF'd and that means you have written something that increases your code's "WTF-per-minute" count (the only valid code quality measurement, right?), and got something to fix to make your intent clearer so you don't have to explain everything your code itself could tell all by itself. What you call "regular assertions" are guard clauses.

Comment: I know two elements is perfectly readable, my critique is about *maintainability*. Performance doesn't weight in, this is your constructor's guard clause for Heaven's sake. I'd more worried about the cyclomatic complexity and code duplication in your performance-critical `Read` method.

Comment: And a *symbol to escape* can change, a *double quote* can't. Pi is *by definition* a constant, you're pulling my leg. A constant shouldn't be called with some vague name that makes it look like a variable, otherwise just make it `static readonly` instead of a `const`.  But who cares, it's `private`. Know that changing a public constant's value is a breaking change that requires recompilation of all client code that refers to it. This isn't *just semantics*.

Comment: An identifier should imply why a value exist, it should not mirror the value, thats when literals are used. And whether Pi is more deserving of a constant than the element of a format is arbitrary. A program constant doesn't need some scientific truth to be valid, thats just ridiculous.

Comment: A guard clause evaluates a boolean value, the region called "regular assertion" doesn't do that, actually it provides a potential guard clause with a boolean value to evaluate.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: Nothing is more arbitrary than your decision that the mathematical constant Pi is just as variable as `Sym_Escape` which, I might add, has an underscore in the middle of it, which is almost universally bad in C#. Additionally, you're mentioning performance considerations such as inlining and not using an array for a character comparison. If the performance difference was noticeable, you might have a point. Mostly, it makes your code more brittle and ugly. If you truly value performance over code quality, try C. All C is not bad, but it'd let you be as bad as you want.

Comment: @Mat'sMugP You're right, a symbol to escape can change.  Which is why it needs to be named `EscapePrefix`, not `DoubleQuote`.  I disagree strongly with naming any constant `DoubleQuote`, either it IS `'"'`, in which case the code would be more readable if it used `'"'`, or else it is something else, in which case the name is terribly confusing.  Replacing a doubled escape character is a common pattern that works with more than just double quotes, depending on context.

Comment: @BenVoigt - The escape character `"` is a delimiter, not a prefix. The symbol is treated as a value prefix but not exclusively. The same character is used to mark the end of the value, or atleast it should in any sane situation.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: That's not actually an escape character at all.  Perhaps you need `OpenQuote` and `CloseQuote`.  How would you allow embedded quotes in a system where open and close quotes are not the same?  (“Smart quotes”, for example, or «Guillemets»)?  Probably you could encode a close as the pair (open, close).  But then an internal open needs to be encoded also, possibly as (open, open).  This is just basic byte-stuffing.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: In any case, define symbolic constants according to their function, and comments that document the **EXACT** rules of the quoting algorithm you are following.

Comment: It is an escape character, because it makes symbols readable which would otherwise be excluded from the format. Anyway, this is something that points out the flaws of typical CSV.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, GOTOs are evil. You should never touch them, as Dijkstra said, [go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful).

Dont forget to dispose your `StreamReader`, you can implement `IDisposable` to dispose it.

```
public class CsvReader : IDisposable
{
  void Dispose()
  {
     if(null != this.reader)
      {
        this.reader.Dispose()
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is any legitimate reason not to use goto, it must be to avoid prejudgement. Not using goto because it looks prettier the other way is superficial. I didn't implement IDisposable because disposing the stream is the responsibility of the caller. When the caller lends its stream doesn't mean that it should be claimt.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger I didn't understand the first 2 sentences. Anyways, you shouldn't assume that the caller is a nice chap and he is gonna close the stream

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: It's *your* `StreamReader`, held in a private member.  How can it be the caller's responsibility to dispose what he can't access?  You can use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don't want to pull the rug out from under your caller by closing his stream.  Even better, provide a boolean parameter of your own to allow the caller to select between automatic and manual disposal.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi You missed the point, closing the stream is not the responsiblity of a reader. `StreamReader.Dispose()` is just a shortcut.

Comment: @Ben I don't think you understand what the Dispose method does, it closes the underlying stream which is definitely accessible by the caller. Any resources used by the reader are released by the GC.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: It does that only if you used the wrong constructor.  Don't count on dispose not doing anything else.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: 1. You have a stream. 2. You should close it.

Comment: @Magus: 3. Unless your contract with the caller says not to, in which case you should clean up your `StreamReader` and not the underlying stream.

Answer (score 6):

If you understand your toolbox (standard library functions) you can make them perform well and not need to reinvent them.

This is crazy:

```
// in constructor

this.initialRowSize = StandardInitialRowSize;

// per-line

string[] row = new string[initialRowSize];
int rowSize = initialRowSize;
int rowPos = 0;

// later

if (rowPos == rowSize)
{
    rowSize *= 2;
    Array.Resize(ref row, rowSize);
}
row[rowPos++] = valueBuilder.ToString();
valueBuilder.Length = 0;

// later

if (rowPos < rowSize)
{
    Array.Resize(ref row, rowPos);
}

outRow = row;

initialRowSize = rowPos;
```

Instead you should be using a `List<string>` for accumulating fields.  It remembers how many items are stored, so you won't need `rowPos`.  And it remembers its capacity, so you won't need `rowSize`.  As well, clearing it doesn't change the capacity, so you won't need `initialRowSize`.  And it already grows exponentially, as needed, so you can get rid of all the tests comparing `rowPos` to `rowSize`.

Much better:

```
//class variable
private readonly List<string> workingRow = new List<string>(StandardInitialRowSize);

// at beginning of row processing
workingRow.Clear(); // resets Length to zero, retaining capacity and allocated array

// adding value to row
workingRow.Add(valueBuilder.ToString());
valueBuilder.Length = 0;

// at end
outRow = workingRow.ToArray();
```

That even gets rid of the need for `goto SetValue`, because now the value-setting code is so dirt simple it can safely be repeated.

I notice you already did this exact thing with `valueBuilder`, so why not with the `string[]`?  `List<string>` is to `string[]` as `StringBuilder` is to `string`.

Comment: I know someone's going to tell me that `new List<string>` is expensive and restarts the growth.  That's why I suggested a method that doesn't create a new list for each row!

Comment: Lists are alot more expensive overall, not just initialization. Reusing the same object representing a row is not an option. An unreliable program could corrupt the collection causing the reader to malfunction. Besides when a utilizer retrieves a row, it may directly rely on it, changing the collection is unacceptable.

Comment: 1. No they are not more expensive. They are very thin wrappers around array access that gets inlined.  You may be thinking of costs of the IList interface, which I did not recommend using. 2. The list is not exposed to the caller anywhere. 3. If you aren't going to fully read the reviews, don't bother posting on CR. It is clear that you focused on "use List" and skipped 2/3rds of my answer.

Comment: Fyi, I have not skipped any part of your answer. I responded to your comment. And regarding the lists, I have benchmarked this, you obviously have not.

Comment: I used `StringBuilder` because of performance. Unlike `char[]`, `StringBuilder` is capable of of calling the internal copy methods of `string`.

Comment: @leopold: if you had understood my answer you would not have written that "an unreliable program could corrupt the collection". You assumed that I intended you to return the list, when my answer clearly uses ToArray to get a distinct array of the exact right size, not requiring any extra resizing step as your code has. Using list will improve the clarity of your code immensely. I'd you want to go one step further and write your own arraybuilder class that avoids the extra copy in the (probably common) case that all iterations have the same number of columns, do so. But you're dismissi

Comment: Whether list or custom arraybuilder, the important thing is to get the buffer management logic out of the read function, and into a separate class so it can be thoroughly tested.

Comment: I have obviously tested the buffer logic and it works fine. Building an array is not a big deal. If you're interested to know how I implemented this in the successor, then see my new question.

Answer (score 5):

> GOTO is nice if used appropriately

That's a big IF.  Throwing it into a method which is several hundred lines and already has a cyclomatic complexity in the double digits is not appropriate.

Comment: Again, prejudice. My benchmark tells me otherwise.

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger: Your benchmark says nothing of the sort.  Perhaps it shows that you got great performance from code containing GOTO.  It does not prove that the same performance cannot be achieved from code without GOTO.

Comment: Performance has nothing to do with the goto statements.

Comment: This seems to be a critique of a comment and not the OP's code. (Seriously though, GOTOs are the devil. [99.999999999% of the time])

Comment: @LeopoldAsperger As far as I can see, you were the one who started talking about performance, seemingly implying that `goto`s make your code faster.

Comment: @svick No. My comment was regarding cyclomatic complexity, but I see the implication.

Answer (score 5):

### Bug fix

As I mentioned in the comments, `outRow = new string[1]` should be `outRow = new string[0]`.

### API

The only time you return `false`, is when you set `outRow` to `null`. I would suggest changing the function signature to

```
public string[] Read()
```

Then client code would look like

```
string[] row;
while ((row = csvReader.Read()) != null)
```

How do you know that the proper encoding is UTF8? Let the client pass in their own `StreamReader` and use that.

You could use the more general `TextReader` in place of `StreamReader`, by checking for the end of the input using `Read` instead of `EndOfStream`.

### `StreamReader`

I find it surprising that nowhere do you call `this.reader.ReadLine()`, as CSV is a line-based format.

### Data structures

You're resizing your `row` array, which suggests a `List<string>` would be a better option.

### Naming

The method `Assert` does not contain any assertions, so I would suggest renaming it.

### Control flow

There are parts in the code that are of the form

```
if (...)
{
    ...
    return;
}
else if (...)
{
}
```

or

```
if (...)
{
    ...
    break;
}
else if (...)
{
}
```

In which case, you don't need the `else`.

### Other

`valueBuilder`, `reader`, `buffer`, `bufferSize`, and `delimiter` can be made readonly.

`StringBuilder.Clear` is a convenience method for `sb.Length = 0`, and reads a bit nicer.

Comment: `new string[1]` is not a "bug", it represents an implicit row. Having a row with no value doesn't make sense, therefore it has one empty value. `Assert` does cause assertion, but it doesn't return a boolean value. I've used `else` in those cases for readability, it will compile to the same IL. `StringBuilder.Clear` is only available in .NET 4.0. Everything else is too opinion-based.

Comment: @Magus: The array is the row.  The number of elements are the columns/fields/values.

Comment: I do not intend to intialize an empty array. What I intend to do is initialize an array with 1 empty string value.